# creating a bubble in UITableView for chat application in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource, uibubbletableview

I am trying to create a `UIBubbleTableView` in my `UITableview`. I searched an example on the internet and tried exactly the same thing. But the example used xib, and i am using `storyboard`.
I have imported the file given in example in my project. But when i try to run that code, it gets crashed saying.-

> -[UITableView setBubbleDataSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here below is what i tried.

```
@interface ChatController (){

IBOutlet UIView *textView;
IBOutlet UITextField *textF1;
NSMutableArray *bubbleData1;
IBOutlet UIBubbleTableView *bubbleTbl;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//bubble data
NSBubbleData *heyBubble1 = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:@"Hey, halloween is soon" date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-300] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
heyBubble1.avatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar1.png"];

NSBubbleData *photoBubble1 = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"halloween.jpg"] date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-290] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
photoBubble1.avatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar1.png"];

NSBubbleData *replyBubble1 = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:@"Wow.. Really cool picture out there. iPhone 5 has really nice camera, yeah?" date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-5] type:BubbleTypeMine];
replyBubble1.avatar = nil;

bubbleData1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:heyBubble1, photoBubble1, replyBubble1, nil];
bubbleTbl.bubbleDataSource = self;
}
```

the app crashes on this line. - `bubbleTbl.bubbleDataSource = self`;

I tried to connect the 'bubbleTbl' outlet to my `tableview`, But couldn't connect it hence i don't know how to 'set `bubbleDataSource`' to my `Tableview`.

Can anyone please help me out. Any help is appreciated

EDIT-

I have implemented this method and have set a breakpoint on this method. But this method never gets executed.

```
- (NSInteger)rowsForBubbleTable:(UIBubbleTableView *)tableView
{

NSLog(@"bubble count %lu",(unsigned long)[bubbleData1 count]);
return [bubbleData1 count];
}
```

EDIT 2-

code for showing video in bubble-

```
UIEdgeInsets insetss = { .left = 180, .right = 10, .top =10, .bottom = 200 };
NSBubbleData *videodata=[NSBubbleData dataWithView:_playerViewController.view date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeMine insets:(insetss)];
[bubbleData1 addObject:videodata];
```

EDIT 3--

```
NSString *stringVideoName = @"videobuild.mov";
NSString *stringVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:stringVideoName ofType:nil];
NSAssert(stringVideoPath, @"Expected not nil video file");

NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringVideoPath];
NSAssert(urlVideoFile, @"Expected not nil video url");

_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlVideoFile];
_playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 150.0 , 80.0);  //   self.view.bounds;
_playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in xib/storyboard to `UITableView` in class - `UIBubbleTableView`

[image]

Comment: How many rows do you have in UITableView? If rows count > 0 then check Cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Are you sure that you have a reference on bubbleTbl? if bubbleTbl == nil then rowsForBubbleTable will not call. Set breakpoint on bubbleTbl.bubbleDataSource = self and check. And this reference must be strong

Comment: @ MirMiratom  -can you tell me about how to send images in chat application (image should be present in bubble)

Comment: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name_you_image"];
    NSBubbleData *photoBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:image date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
    [bubbleData addObject:photoBubble];
    [bubbleTable reloadData];

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: can we also insert a video in that chat bubble like images as you suggested above?. If yes, how can we achieve this?

Comment: When you add image to chat, you use initWithImage method. This method create UIImageView and call this method [self initWithView:imageView date:date type:type insets:insets]; . You just need create method initWithViewURL and create some videoPlayer and call  initWithView with this player

Comment: @ MirMiratom - see my edit2- I am able to add video in my chat bubble. But the video frame is going out of the bubble. Can you please suggest whats wrong?

Comment: What is class you use for play video?

Comment: AVFoundation and AVKit

Comment: in method initWithURLVideo(which you created for video)  create this [link](http://joxi.ru/krD07Ju07Gwkrp) . Just create UIView with frame and add AVPlayer layer to this UIView

Comment: i have not created any init method for urlVideo. Please check my new edit for adding video view in bubble label

Comment: just try to remove insets

Comment: when i remove insets, it fits into the label. But when i scroll up and down the table view, the background bubble gets vanished and the height of the video player goes on increasing, every time i scroll the table view. Why so?

Comment: ok one last question. Can you tell me how to add a check(tick) on every label (at right bottom corner )so that the users get informed about messages sent or delivered,etc...please.

Comment: Hmm.. You need some service/notification which will tell you that your interlocutor received message.
What about UI - you can add UIImageView to each bubbles and set some image when user read or receive message

Comment: -can you please tell me how to change the bubble present in chat with new custom view, i tried adding a new view to bubble data but it loads new bubble. Also it does not have the new view in it. Please help me.

Comment: It is out of scope of this question. So you should ask for this separately IMO.